# How can I plot only one text in a jitter plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot only once the text of the mean for the specific cluster.

So I have followed plot:
[image]

but what I want is this:

[image]

code for reproduction:

```
price_l <- rep(c('€€-€€€', '€€-€€€', '€€€€', '€€-€€€', '€€-€€€', 
             '€€-€€€', '€€€€', '€€-€€€', '€€€€', '€€-€€€', 
             '€€-€€€', '€€-€€€', '€€-€€€', '€€-€€€', 
             '€€-€€€', '€€-€€€', '€€-€€€', '€€-€€€', '€€€€','€', '€', 
             '€', '€','€€€€', '€'),100)

avg_r <- rep(c(4.5, 3.5, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 3.5, 4.5, 4.0, 3.0, 4.0, 
           3.0, 5.0, 4.5, 4.0, 3.0,
           3.5, 4.5, 3.5, 3.5, 4.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 2.5, 4.5),100)


sub.df <- data.frame(price_l, avg_r)


sub.df %>%    
  group_by(price_l) %>%
  mutate(mean = mean(avg_r)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(sub.df, mapping=aes(price_l, avg_r), na.rm=T) +
  geom_jitter(aes(colour = price_l)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = sprintf("%.2f",mean)))
```

Comment: Missing a `+` after `geom_jitter(.)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `y` value manually inside the `geom_text`

```r
sub.df %>%    
  group_by(price_l) %>%
  mutate(mean = mean(avg_r)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(sub.df, mapping=aes(price_l, avg_r), na.rm=T) +
  geom_jitter(aes(colour = price_l)) +
  geom_text(aes(y = 3.5, label = sprintf("%.2f",mean)),
            check_overlap = TRUE, size = 6, fontface = 2)
```

[image]

Or, as r2evans suggests:

```r
sub.df %>%    
  group_by(price_l) %>%
  mutate(mean = mean(avg_r)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(sub.df, mapping=aes(price_l, avg_r), na.rm=T) +
  geom_jitter(aes(colour = price_l)) +
  geom_text(aes(y = mean, label = sprintf("%.2f",mean)),
            check_overlap = TRUE, size = 6, fontface = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: `aes(y=mean, label=..)`?

Comment: @r2evans yes, although that doesn't match as well as the desired output demonstrated by the OP. I'll add it as an option though.

Comment: Agreed, not sure if that was intentional or a side-effect of not controlling overlaps/duplicity.

Comment: (But to me, placing `3.90` anywhere other than at 3.9 on the y-axis seems ... uncomfortable :-)

Answer (score 5):

We could use `stat_summary(aes(label = ..y..), geom = "text", fun = mean, color="black", size = 6, fontface = 2)`

```
sub.df %>%    
  group_by(price_l) %>%
  mutate(mean = mean(avg_r)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(sub.df, mapping=aes(price_l, avg_r), na.rm=T) +
  geom_jitter(aes(colour = price_l)) +
  stat_summary(aes(label = ..y..), geom = "text", fun = mean, color="black", size = 6, fontface = 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, here's a way to do this using `stat_summary()`.  This has an advantage over the previous method in that: (1) there's no need to summarize beforehand via `group_by()`... `mutate()`... functions, and (2) it avoids overplotting that will occur if you use `geom_text()`.

The answer proposed using `geom_text()` alone works just fine for the result, but you'll note that this will result in overplotting.  The reason is that `geom_text()` like all other geoms will draw "a thing" on the plot for every observation in the dataset.  The dataframe resulting from the pipe (`%>%`) commands above the initial `ggplot()` call should have 2500 observations.  This means that if you ask `geom_text()` to create a label/text at a specific position, it will do so... 2500 times.

To avoid this, you should do one of two things:

1. Create a separate dataframe of aggregated data containing only 3 observations (three pieces of text here) and use `geom_text(data = that_new_dataframe...)`, or
2. Use `stat_summary()` and have that do all the summarizing for you based on the original dataset, `sub.df`.

For the `stat_summary()` method, you can create a userfunction to return a `label` and `y` value (satisfying the aesthetics required for `geom_text()` and then apply that to your dataset within `stat_summary()` via the `fun.data=` argument:

```
my_fun <- function(x){
  return(data.frame(y=mean(x), label=sprintf("%.2f", mean(x))))
}

sub.df %>%    
  ggplot(sub.df, mapping=aes(price_l, avg_r), na.rm=T) +
  geom_jitter(aes(colour = price_l)) +
  stat_summary(
    geom="text", fun.data="my_fun", size=8,
    aes(group=price_l)
  )
```

[image]

*Note: after posting this I realize it's similar to @TarJae's answer... but kept it here due to the further explanation.*